# ImportError: No module named '_bz2' (or '_bz2.BZ2Compressor' is unknown)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, libreoffice

I have a problem.
ImportError: No module named '_bz2' (or '_bz2.BZ2Compressor' is unknown).
I use a windows device and i want to run the code with LibreOffice (7.2)
I see a lot of response but it doesn't work for windows.

Thank you

So i tried to use command but it doesn't work for windows. My code run with python in my machine but not with LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in LibreOffice: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=116412.

From what I gather of the bug report, you need to install `bz2` in the LO python distro yourself. I tried this by using `get-pip.py` and then `chdir "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program"; & ./python -m pip install bz2`.

However, pip was not able to find an appropriate package for my version. Perhaps downloading and installing a `bz2` package manually would work, although another SO question mentions that bz2 has a lot of dependencies, so it might be difficult.

Ultimately, it's likely you'll need to make a choice: either remove the bz2 dependency from your code or else run that part from your system python instead of the LO python distribution.